# adding month to EndDate as constraint in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a question regarding Oracle database SQL.

my employee each have a project, the end date of the project depends on the no of months that was given to them base on PTerm. Am i right to do it this way?

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT ( P_ID VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
                   PNAME VARCHAR ( 100 ) NOT NULL,
                   PTERM VARCHAR ( 20 ),
                   PSTARTDATE DATE,
                   PENDDATE DATE,
                   CONSTRAINT PROJECT_PKEY PRIMARY KEY ( P_ID ),
                   CONSTRAINT PROJECT_PTERM CHECK
                       ( PTERM IN ('1 MONTH', '2 MONTH', '3 MONTH') ),
                   CONSTRAINT PROJECT_ENDDATE CHECK
                       ( PENDDATE = (PSTARTDATE + PTERM) ) );
```

Comment: What flavor of SQL and which concrete database product is this for? Things are often very quickly vendor-specific.... so is this for MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM Db2? Something else entirely? Please **update your tags** accordingly!

Comment: You might consider removing the `PENDDATE` column from the table altogether, and instead calculate it as needed (for example, using a view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is Oracle then I would go this way

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT ( P_ID VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
                   PNAME VARCHAR ( 100 ) NOT NULL,
                   PTERM VARCHAR ( 20 ),
                   PSTARTDATE DATE,
                   PENDDATE DATE,
                   CONSTRAINT PROJECT_PKEY PRIMARY KEY ( P_ID ),
                   CONSTRAINT PROJECT_PTERM CHECK
                       ( PTERM IN ('1', '2', '3') ),
                   CONSTRAINT PROJECT_ENDDATE CHECK
                       ( PENDDATE = ADD_MONTHS(PSTARTDATE , PTERM) ) );
```

If I try the below inserts they would fail since it strictly add months to the start date and expect the same as end.

```
INSERT INTO
      PROJECT
VALUES
      ( 1,
        'asb',
        2,
        SYSDATE,
        SYSDATE
        + 60 );
--ORA-02290: check constraint (PROJECT_ENDDATE) violated

INSERT INTO
      PROJECT
VALUES
      ( 1,
        'asb',
        2,
        SYSDATE,
        SYSDATE
        + 62 );
--ORA-02290: check constraint (PROJECT_ENDDATE) violated

INSERT INTO
      PROJECT
VALUES
      ( 1,
        'asb',
        2,
        SYSDATE,
        SYSDATE
        + 61 );  
-- 1 row inserted
```

Comment: hmm, is it part of a good practice to script everything in caps?

Comment: I made my own rules for all my projects :) But if you have any formatting tools which has your own rule definitions, you can just paste the snippet and go for formatting. I do Ctrl+Shift+F in toad with my settings

Answer (score 0):

OK I just saw you mention Oracle so I would try this

```
 CREATE TABLE PROJECT (

P_ID          VARCHAR(20) not null,
PName         VARCHAR(100) not null,
PTerm         VARCHAR(20),
PStartDate    DATE,
PEndDate      DATE,
constraint project_Pkey primary key (P_ID),
constraint project_pterm CHECK ( PTERM IN 
                        ('1 MONTH', '2 MONTH', '3 MONTH')),
constraint project_enddate CHECK(PEndDate = (add_months(PStartDate, to_number(substr(pTerm, 1, 1)))))

);
```

I believe it would be better if you had a field that indicated the number of months in number(10) instead of varchar so you could use this field instead of making all this substr and to_number convertion in a varchar field

Comment: hmmm, may i know why is pTer, 1,1?

Comment: i kept the constraints as stated by you. If the values are '1 Month', '2 Month' etc, then we needed the integer part. That's why I state you should prefer to have a field that will keep the months as a number. In that case the constraint would be constraint project_enddate CHECK(PEndDate = (add_months(PStartDate, pTerm)))